# How to remove the strap from the Joy-Con strap?

Tags: hardware, nintendo-switch

Is there a way to remove the strap from the Joy-Con strap attachment for the Nintendo Switch?

Note that I'm not asking how to remove the attachment from a Joy-Con (which can be tricky if put on incorrectly), but rather how to remove the string/strap itself from the attachment. I could just cut it off, but I figured there's a less destructive way of doing it.

Comment: I've always kinda wondered that too.  I don't understand what the "lock" does on the strap.

Comment: @JMac I'm pretty sure the "lock" toggle locks the attachment to the Joy-Con.

Comment: @HarrisonPaine It doesn't seem to.  I always have them "locked" but they come out fine.

Comment: @JMac The lock stops the strap from detaching from the joy-con when the strap is connected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised nobody has done a teardown video of the strap accessory yet, but you can in fact disassemble it and remove the strap. I don't have pictures, but here's the process.

**WARNING**: Performing these steps may void your warranty. There are several tiny pieces that may be lost or damaged during this process. Also, the white locking tab may be a looser than normal without the strap in place.

1. Remove the 3 screws on the inside of the metal track.
2. Lift the metal track out of the plastic housing. Watch out for the little black bar with the locking pins on it as it will likely fall out.
3. Carefully remove the spring that is under the locking pin bar.
4. Lift out the black plastic cover that runs the length of the interior by lifting up on the end opposite the strap. The white locking tab is slotted into this piece, and if you try and force it out from the strap end you will likely break the tab.
5. You should see the strap's end now. Both ends come to meet in a metal crimp. You can lift this up and remove the strap as well as the white locking tab.
6. Reassemble by reversing the steps.